# Android Database Query Cross-row Check

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am working on a project which requires me to do some query in android database. However, I am completely new to database and I am a little confused at how to deal with such scenarios. Here's a rough example to show my question.

For a table like this:

TableA:

```
--------------------------------------------------------
|  _id  |  name   |  mimetype  | data1 | data2 | data3 |
--------------------------------------------------------
|    1  |  user1  |     mime1  |  val1 |  val2 |     x |
--------------------------------------------------------
|    2  |  user1  |     mime2  |  val3 |  val4 |     y |
--------------------------------------------------------
|    3  |  user1  |     mime3  |  val8 |  val5 |     a |
--------------------------------------------------------  
|    4  |  user2  |     mime2  |  val6 |  val7 |     q |
--------------------------------------------------------
|    5  |  user2  |     mime3  |  val9 | val10 |     a |
--------------------------------------------------------
|    6  |  user3  |     mime1  | val11 | val12 |     b |
--------------------------------------------------------
```

Basically, I want to do a query to return data from columns of name, data1, data2 from TABLE A when it fits the following criteria:

1. mimetype = mime2
2. there's another row in the table that has the same name and its mimetype = mime3 and data3 = a

I am wondering how to do this in one query.

If anyone can give some direction on how to figure this out, it will be great! Thanks!

Comment: Please provide some sample data and your desired output. (See [How to
format SQL tables in a Stack Overflow
post?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96125) for how to add some.)

Comment: Thanks for the info, I've made it a table now, though not very good looking, Lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with the [EXISTS operator](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#in_op) and a [correlated subquery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery):

```
SELECT ...
FROM TableA
WHERE mimetype = 'mime2'
  AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM TableA AS T2
              WHERE T2.name = TableA.name
                AND T2.mimetype = 'mime3'
                AND T2.data3 = 'a');
```

Comment: what does the "1" in line 4 referring to? Also when you are comparing T2.name = TableA.name, it sounds like that "1" is referring to a copy of tableA. Would you explain this a little bit?

Comment: Read the documentation I linked to.

Comment: Thank you, though I decided to use subquery IN at the end. The sample helps a lot!